# What's the meaning of "chopped the bill off to fight"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm reading "The Old Man and The Sea" a novel by Ernest Hemingway. There is small paragraph that I don't understand completely because of that statement "chopped the bill off to fight". I quote that paragraph below to give more context.

> He liked to think of the fish and what he could do to a shark if he were swimming free. I should have chopped the bill off to fight them with, he thought. But there was no hatchet and then there was no knife.

What does it mean in this context? Is it an idiom? I couldn't find adequate description in dictionary.

Comment: Did you mean 'hatchet'? Do you know what a 'bill-hook' is?

Comment: Yes, I mean hatchet, updated the post, thanks. I didn't know just checked its meaning, "versatile cutting tool used widely in agriculture and forestry" but still not clear "chopped the bill off to fight " meaning.

Comment: On boats and ships a bill hook or just "bill" is often fixed to the end of a long wooden pole. Google it. If it is separated from the pole, e.g. by chopping the pole with a hatchet (small axe) it could be used as a hand weapon.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. I can accept it if you post it as an answer below.